# MongoDB and dynamic query building with $push statement with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic, field, updating

I'm creating an application where I need to keep version of each field in database when update is performed. So I figured that I would use statement like this to accomplish it.

```
 collection.update({ _id: id },
            {
                $push: { placeholder : { $each: [{ data: keyValue, timeStamp: date, editor: editorID}] } }
            },
```

The placeholder is a field which might be different each time depending which field I'm updating in the table.

```
var key = req.body.key;
var keyValue = req.body.keyValue;
var editorID = req.body.editor;
var date = new Date();
```

The above variables are initialized  based on the form submitted and the **key** is the name of the database filed which I would like to use instead of placeholder.

How can I make the placeholder to represent database field name passed from the form?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
var query = {};   
query[key] = { data: keyValue, timeStamp: date, editor: editorID };
```

and then

```
collection.update({ _id: id },
            {
                 $push:query              
             }
            },
```